# Observing light speed

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, observers

Consider an observer B is moving with speed $0.8c$ relative to another observer A in standard-configuration (I think it is called that in english: that the system B is only moving along the $x$-axis of system A).

- At what speed will A observe the light leave the system B in the direction in which B travels away from A? Is it just $0.2c$ or would you have to use the velocity-addition formula to calculate it?
- And what about the light leaving system B in the opposite direction (towards A) seen from A relative to B? B would observe the speed as being the same in every direction (c) relative to itself, but would A see the light moving with the same speed relative to B in every directions?
- If that is actually true, then the speed of light is not the same observed by A relative to A, so I guess they would observe different happenings? So how would one calculate the speed of light emitted by B relative to B as observed by A in different directions?

Remember I do not ask about the speed relative to any of the systems themselves observed inside the system as that would always be $c$. I hope you understand the question. I gladly accept mathematical explanations.

Comment: Probably useful reading: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143576/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2230/

Answer (score 1):

All inertial observers (including A) will see light move at exactly $c$.  So both A and B see the light move at $c$.  But from A's frame, it appears that the light moves with a speed relative to B of $(c - 0.8c) = 0.2c$.  Likewise the light in the other direction would be observed by A to be moving relative to B at $(c + 0.8c) = 1.8c$

As long as you are asking questions about relative speeds in a single frame (that of A in the example), we can use simple vector addition.

There is no problem with measured relative speeds in excess of $c$, because nothing physical is really moving at that rate relative to an inertial frame.  As an example, two photons fired in opposite directions will have a distance between them that is measured to be increasing at the rate of $2c$.

Comment: Then how can you explain B observing the light leaving B with speed c? I understand how both observers messure the same speed in front of B (because lenght contraction and time dilation), but how can one explain that both observers messure same speed behind B with relativity consequences?

Comment: It's because B doesn't measure time the same way A does.  If we imagine two objects an equal distance in front and behind B, then the light reaches those objects at a time that is simultaneous in B's frame, but is not simultaneous in A's frame.  But both observe the speed of the light to be the same

Comment: See also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/199891/einstein-on-a-train-paradox-whats-the-resolution

Comment: I agree that the time dilation and length contraction is the explanation, but I can't seem to get a picture of what is happening in my head. Yes, it does explain, but how/why?

Comment: In this video at 3 min. there is an easy video picturing and explaining what happans in front of B, but how does that explain what happens behind B? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ACUuFg9Y9dY

Comment: Observed by A the light moves slower relative to B, because B's length is shorter than A's and time is running slower. But why does that no count behind B and only in front of B?

Comment: After some research I think I get it. It is explained by non-simultaneity.

Comment: Malthe-Andersen Still today, over 99% are not interested in teaching the "How/Why" explanation concerning SR. Instead, you receive just a "What is" explanation of Special Relativity. If you have 1 hour and 37 min. to spare, and are still interested in the "How/Why" part of the picture, watch the YouTube video (divided into 9 parts) at http://goo.gl/fz4R0I .

Comment: The how/why is the important part. You learn nothing by saying it just is this way and don't try to understand or develop the concept. It is sad really